# gcc saying "assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Ok so I keep getting this error:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g translate.c support.c scanner.c -o translate
translate.c: In function ‘main’:
translate.c:22:16: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     dictionary = createArray(count);
            ^
support.c: In function ‘readTokens’:
support.c:66:18: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
         a[count] = token;
              ^
```

and I don't know why.

here's my main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "support.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    int count;
    char** dictionary;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("need two arguments!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    count = countTokens(argv[1]);
    printf("there are %d tokens and strings\n", count);

    dictionary = createArray(count);

    readTokens(argv[1], dictionary);

    printf("The dictionary:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", dictionary[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my create arrays function:

```
char* createArray(int count) {
    char* a;
    a = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
    if (a == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return a;
}
```

and its header

`char * createArray(int);`

I have no idea how to get this to go away. I've tried taking away and adding asteriks and changing from one equal signs to two, but it's not working. 2nd year cs student, first year in C. Any help would be appreciated a million times over. Thanks!

Comment: `dictionary = createArray(count);` assigns a `char *` to a `char **`.

Comment: Could you add your `readTokens()` function definition?

Comment: its below. this is the one that really gave me trouble. thank you so much for the createArray answer and responding so quickly :)

Comment: `
void
readTokens(char *fileName, char** a[])
    {
    FILE *fp;
    char *token;
    int count = 0;

    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"file %s could not be opened for reading\n", fileName);
        exit(1);
        }
                
    token = readLine(fp);
    while(!feof(fp))
        {
        a[count] = token;
        ++count;
        free(token);
        token = readLine(fp);
        }

    fclose(fp);
    }


`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `createArray` functions is declared and implement with a mistake. You need an array of char pointers, which is of type (`char **`), so create and return such an array:

```
char** createArray(int count) {
    char** a;
    a = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
    if (a == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Almost the same answer as mine, but 6 seconds later!

Answer (score 5):

Your `createArrray` has the wrong signature. Try instead

```
char** createArray(unsigned count) {
  char** a = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
  if (a == NULL) {
    perror("createArray"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return a;
 }
```

Of course change the declaration in your header file accordingly:

```
char** createArray(unsigned);
```

BTW, you are right in compiling with `gcc -Wall -g`. Now try to run your program step by step in the `gdb` debugger.

NB: there is no point in having `count` declared as `int` (morally, it cannot be negative).

Answer (score 3):

You are not counting your stars.

```
Foo* foo =                        // 1 star
     malloc(sizeof(Foo));         // 0 stars

Foo** foo =                       // 2 stars
     malloc(sizeof(Foo*));        // 1 star

Foo******* foo =                 // N stars
     malloc(sizeof(Foo******));  // N-1 stars
```

If your count is different, you are doing it wrong.

Of course this is just a safety check. You need to understand what each `*` does in your code.

The dictionary is `char**`. Why? It's an array (the first `*`) of strings(the second `*`). So it cannot be `char` or `char*` or `char***`. So on the right hand side of the assignment you need a `char**` too, so `createArray` must return `char**`, and `a` must be a `char**`, and inside the sizeof inside the malloc you need N-1=1 star.