# two dimensional Matrix allocation

Tags: c++, malloc

I am trying to create a two-dimensional matrix as shown below

```
#include <iostream>

int** createMatrix();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 using std::cout;
 int** m1=createMatrix();
 std::cout << sizeof m1;
}
int** createMatrix() {
int rows = 1000;
int cols = 1000;
int **matrix = (int **) malloc( rows * sizeof(int) );
 int *const row_ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * cols * rows);
 for(int i=0;i< rows;i++){
   matrix[i] = &row_ptr[i * cols];
 }
 return matrix;
 }
```

this code works fine when the rows and cols value is up to 100 * 100 values; However, when I increase it beyond 100 * 100, I am getting the following error.

`malloc(): corrupted top size`

`Aborted (core dumped)`

could someone point of the issue?

Thanks

Comment: C++ and C are diffrent languages. `<iostream>` suggests C++, so please remove the C tag.

Comment: A side note: in C++ is is better to use a container like `std::vector` instead of a raw C arrays. For a matrix I recommend a 1D `std::vector` with manual management of indices (idx = y * width + x).

Comment: `malloc( rows * sizeof(int) );` are you on a platform where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`? No? Then this buffer is too small, you wrote out of bounds and thereby caused a heap corruption.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25750950/775806

Comment: Since this is C++ please don't tag with C. Further, being C++ code, you should forget all about `malloc`. Just pretend you never heard about it. Use standard containers or if you really want to use `new`

Comment: Check out [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: If you are not doing this for education or masochism, do [something like this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36123944/4581301). If this is for education, the most important things to know is the array of pointers to arrays is hard to code, hard to manage, and slow all at the same time. It loses on pretty much every level. Don't do this in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
int **matrix = (int **) malloc( rows * sizeof(int) );
```

Remember, you want to allocate an array of pointers to integers, not an array of integers.

On 64-bit platforms `sizeof(int)` is typically 4 and `sizeof(int*)` is 8.  Hence, you are allocating half as much memory as you need.

On 32-bit platforms, it will "just happen to work" since `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`  Hence, you really want this:

```
int **matrix = (int **) malloc( rows * sizeof(int*) );
```

That should fix your issue.